# What is the meaning of ~. in R?

Tags: r, knn

I would like to understand the meaning of `~.` in R. This is an example from kknn function:

```
library(kknn)

data(iris)
m <- dim(iris)[1]
val <- sample(1:m, size = round(m/3), replace = FALSE, prob = rep(1/m, m)) 
iris.learn <- iris[-val,]
iris.valid <- iris[val,]
iris.kknn <- kknn(Species~., iris.learn, iris.valid, distance = 1, kernel = "triangular")
summary(iris.kknn)
fit <- fitted(iris.kknn)
table(iris.valid$Species, fit)
```

It is included on the kknn function above, right beside the Species.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/kknn/versions/1.3.1/topics/kknn),
 you are creating a formula object. The [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/formula.html) of formula states:

> There are two special interpretations of . in a formula. The usual one
>   is in the context of a data argument of model fitting functions and
>   means ‘all columns not otherwise in the formula’

So in your case, you are creating a model that uses all other variables than 'Species' as predictors to predict Species.

Comment: Now I understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here ~ is a separator, and . stands for all other attributes.
Here you mean that, you have to predict Species~[separator] based on all other attributes[.]

Comment: Thanks for explaining/elaborating!